# Attempting to use Logstash to keep my Elasticsearch in sync with my SQL Server database throws field mapping exceptions

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to use logstash to keep my SQL Server database in sync with Elasticsearch. Here is my configuration file (logstash-config.conf)

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://jobDatabaseHost:port;DatabaseName=jobDBname;integratedSecurity=true"
    jdbc_user => "xxxx"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\sqljdbc_4.2.8112.200_enu\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    statement => "SELECT TOP (50) 
      JobID as jobId, JobName as jobName, JobDescription as jobDescription, JobStatus as jobStatus
      from jobTable"
    }
  }
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["http://jobhost:9200"]
    index => "jobIndex"
    document_type => "doc"
    document_id => "%{jobId}"
    user => "Christian.***@***.com"
    password => "*****"
    }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

My question is: how does **logstash** match the database columns with the Elasticsearch fields? My *actual* database query is much lengthier and logstash is constantly throwing field matching errors even though my database column alias name matches with the elasticsearch field name.. the below one has me particularly puzzled, as I believe @version field is self generated by logstash.. will this just not work with strict mappings?

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception", "reason"=>"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [@version] within [doc] is not allowed"}
```

Here is my cmd output after running logstash -f logstash-config.conf

```
{
    "@version" => "1",
    "jobId" => 1,
    "jobDescription" => "Deduction",
    "jobName" => "test",
    "jobStatus" => "active,
```

And the job is unsuccessful.

Additionally I am using sqjljdbc 1.8, logstash 6.6.2, elasticsearch 6.6.2

Comment: How is the index mapping defined? Looks like the index mapping defined is not allowing new properties to be added like `@version`

Comment: the indexed object field names will be either based on what mapping you have already defined. If not defined then it will use the SQL column aliases